moments of sample median is finite when sample size n is large enough

Given $X_1,...,X_{2n+1} \sim f(x)$ iid r.v.'s with continuous pdf $f(x)$, $\mathbb{E}|X_1|<\infty$. Let $X_{(1)},...,X_{(2n+1)}$ be their order statistics. Prove that, given $K\ge2$, there exists $N$ s.t. for all $n>N$,
$$ \mathbb{E}|X_{(n+1)}|^k < \infty, 2\le k \le K $$

I know the pdf of $X_{(n+1)}$ is $f_{(n+1)}(x)=\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!n!} F(x)^n (1-F(x))^n f(x)$, so that we need to prove $\int_\mathbb{R} |x|^k F(x)^n (1-F(x))^n f(x) \mathbb{d}x < \infty$. I guess we could use the $F(x)^n(1-F(x))^n$ term to control $|x|^k$ then use $\mathbb{E}|X_1|<\infty$ to show the integral is finite, but I can't figure out how to.
I googled some papers (1)(2) and they seem to utilize the inverse function of $F(x)$, and I couldn't grasp the proof thoroughly.
Any help will be fully appreciated!

It suffices to find for a given $K\geqslant 2$, an integer $N=N(K)$ such that for each $n>N$, $\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{(n+1)}\rvert^K\right]<\infty$.
Split the integral into two parts:
$$
I_-=\int_{-\infty}^0 \lvert x\rvert^KF(x)^n(1-F(x))^nf(x)dx,\quad I_+=\int_0^\infty \lvert x\rvert^KF(x)^n(1-F(x))^nf(x)dx.
$$
For $I_-$, do the substitution $t=-x$: $I_-=\int_0^\infty \lvert t\rvert^KF(-t)^n(1-F(-t))^nf(-t)dt$. Let
$$
\tau(R):=\mathbb P\left(\lvert X_1\rvert>R\right).
$$
Then for $t>0$, $F(-t)\leq \tau(t)$  hence
$$
I_-\leqslant \int_0^\infty \lvert t\rvert^K \tau(t)^n f(-t)dt.
$$
Since $\mathbb E\lvert X_1\rvert$ is finite, so is $M:=\sup_{t\geq 0}t\tau(t)$
hence we can take $N=K$, so that $I_-$ does not exceed $M^n$.
For $I_+$, the computation is the same (this time, we bound $F(x)^n$ by $1$).

Could you prove that : “ Since $\mathbb E\lvert X_1\rvert$ is finite, so is $M:=\sup_{t\geq 0}t\tau(t)$”? I dont think it is correct.

@NN2 If you do not think that this is correct you have to give arguments. This is Markov's inequality.

OK I see it is from Markov'sinequality.

I figured out another approach by simply expanding $F(x)$ into integral and putting $|x|$ into it: for example the $x<0$ case,
$ |x|F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x |x|f(t)\mathrm{d}t \le \int_{-\infty}^x |t|f(t)\mathrm{d}t\le \mathrm{E}|X_1|$.
